# Implementing a generic function for a trait, which can operate on different number types

Tags: generics, rust, types, traits, type-traits

Is there a better way to implement a common conversion function over primitive number types? I've been struggling to create a more generic version of a trait, that converts a LE byte stream to specific type, and then returns an option float64. In this routine, if a number of specific type is max positive or max (positive-1), it is invalid. It seems this should be possible with a function that takes generics and uses a where clause, but I haven't been able to find a working solution.

```
struct U16([u8;2]);
struct U32([u8;4]);
struct I16([u8;2]);
struct I32([u8;4]);

trait CanNumber {
    fn to_number(&self) -> Option<f64>;
}
impl CanNumber for U16 {
    fn to_number(&self) -> Option<f64> {
        type nt = u16;
        let num: nt = nt::from_le_bytes(self.0);
        if (num == nt::MAX) | (num == (nt::MAX-1)) {
            None
        }
        else {
            Some(num as f64)
        }
    }
}
impl CanNumber for I16 {
    fn to_number(&self) -> Option<f64> {
        type nt = i16;
        let num: nt = nt::from_le_bytes(self.0);
        if (num == nt::MAX) | (num == (nt::MAX-1)) {
            None
        }
        else {
            Some(num as f64)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test0: f64 = U16([1,2]).to_number().unwrap();
    let test1: f64 = I16([1,2]).to_number().unwrap();
    println!("test!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good candidate for a macro.  You can handle this case by writing a trait and then using a macro to perform the implementation across several types.  For example:

```
trait FromFooLittleEndian {
    type Bytes;
    type Number;

    fn from_foo_little_endian(bytes: Self::Bytes) -> Option<Self::Number>;
}

macro_rules! impl_from_little_endian {
    ( $( $ty:path, $bytes:literal );* $( ; )? ) => {
        $(
            impl FromFooLittleEndian for $ty {
                type Bytes = [u8; $bytes];
                type Number = $ty;

                fn from_foo_little_endian(bytes: Self::Bytes) -> Option<Self::Number> {
                    let num = <$ty>::from_le_bytes(bytes);
                    (num < <$ty>::MAX - 1).then_some(num)
                }
            }
        )*
    };
}

impl_from_little_endian!(
    u16, 2; i16, 2;
    u32, 4; i32, 4;
    u64, 8; i64, 8;
);

#[test]
fn foo_little_endian() {
    assert_eq!(Some(42), u16::from_foo_little_endian(42u16.to_le_bytes()));
    assert_eq!(None, u16::from_foo_little_endian(u16::MAX.to_le_bytes()));
    assert_eq!(
        None,
        u16::from_foo_little_endian((u16::MAX - 1).to_le_bytes())
    );
    assert_eq!(
        Some(u16::MAX - 2),
        u16::from_foo_little_endian((u16::MAX - 2).to_le_bytes())
    );
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=67d3014a23b7044c664b7827d3113836))

Note that the term `foo` here is a placeholder for an application-specific name for this kind of byte stream and I would suggest replacing it with an appropriate name in your application.